# Where can I get the key to create a Telemetry Reporter at Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am working on a Visual Studio Code extension, and I would like to use Telemetry to have some insights about the use of the extension.

The Telemetry repository [explains how to create a Reporter](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-telemetry). I believe how the Python extensions [use it](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/blob/master/src/client/telemetry/telemetry.ts) is much better though. **The problem is that documentation is quite bad at how to get the key or where is the dashboard to see the data**.

**Do you know if the Telemetry of a VS Code extension works with Azure Application Insights?** It could make sense, but I'm new to Microsoft world and I wouldn't like start creating a lot of accounts or expend too much time working on that and being wrong :-)

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

After some research and more new accounts at Azure. The answer to this question is **yes**, at least partially. I don't know if there are other ways, but Telemetry with Application Insights (at Azure) works quite well.

Telemetry configuration is something the Microsoft documentation doesn't explain, actually there is not too much información about all the Telemetry usage.